# Error while trying to install e(fx)clipse 3.8.0 via the Eclipse Marketplace

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

I've been trying for a while now to install e(fx)clipse 3.8.0 in Eclipse, but whenever it gets to the half of installation 53% it shows me this error:

```
An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.

session context was:(profile=C__Users_xx_eclipse_java-2022-06_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
Error reading signed content.
invalid entry CRC (expected 0x29926101 but got 0x837847bf)
```

[image: here]

Is there any way to fix it? I tried different solutions, even uninstalled and downloaded again Eclipse but it's not working.

Comment: Duplicate: [I've been trying to install javaFx in Eclipse IDE through but it doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72741378/ive-been-trying-to-install-javafx-in-eclipse-ide-through-but-it-doesnt-work)

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this issue by installing [e(fx)clipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/efxclipse) into the [_Eclipse IDE for Java Developers_ 2022-06](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-06/r/eclipse-ide-java-developers). Is there anything in the error log (go to _Window > Show Views > Error Log_, select an item, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question please)? Are you behind a proxy? Does in the preferences _Install/Update > Trust_ enabling _Trust all content_ help?

Comment: In addition, you might try the following update site (especially if you behind a proxy) via _Help > Install New Software..._: [`https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.8.0/site`](https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.8.0/site) (using HTTPS instead of HTTP).

Comment: Thank you so much howlger, i tried the preferences Install/Update > Trust enabling Trust all content, and it worked, thank you so much ive been stuck on this error for 2 days

Comment: @EngjellBerisha Great that it works now. I'm sorry for you for the trouble this bug has caused. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug of Eclipse Equinox p2 in the new feature of [signing with PGP](https://gitlab.eclipse.org/eclipse-wg/ide-wg/community/-/issues/11). If you can reproduce it with a fresh installation of the [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-06/r/eclipse-ide-java-developers) download from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2022-06/R/eclipse-java-2022-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip) (it might also be caused by using an outdated version of the Eclipse Installer), please report it [here](https://github.com/eclipse-equinox/p2/issues) with the error log (in *Window > Show Views > Error Log*, select the related item, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and paste it into the issue description).

As a workaround, in the **preferences *Install/Update > Trust*** enable ***Trust all content***.